# accessing form tag with selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate a tag on a page, but so far finding it by name/id/xpath have not worked. This is what I've tried to locate it by xpath:

```
db = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form")
```

and also

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='formControl']")
```

Both of these return the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element:
```

It's as if it can not find the form on the page. Any ideas of how to fix?

Here's the beginning of the html on the page:

```
<html>
  <body id="bodyControl" class="PersonalizationPage ContentPage Layout_PageUsesRegions" onunload="closeTimeoutWarningPopupWindow();return true;" onload="return __MasterOnLoad();" onresize="return __MasterOnResize();">
    <form name="formControl" method="post" action="default.wl?appflag=65.14&amp;bhcp=1&amp;MT=208&amp;rs=LAWS2.0&amp;strRecreate=no&amp;sv=Split&amp;transfertoken=10281204301250d0dbca913e4aa6887c7d425f4ede9c&amp;vr=2.0" id="formControl" target="_top">
```

Comment: Doesn't look like there's something wrong. Could you post more of your code ? (the part where you read the HTML page). Can you access the /body tag ? Or even the /html tag ? Are you sure the driver is reading some data from the webpage ?

Comment: yep, I accessed the body by db = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body"). What do you mean 'read the html page'? I'm just using selenium webdriver and relying on it to be able to parse the page.

Comment: Is it the only form on the page? You're two methods work fine for me. Have you tried just using the XPath `//form`?

Comment: Is your form close tag present ? Is the HTML markup valid ?

Comment: Are there any frames on the html page?

Comment: no, there aren't. It appears that the element may be loaded with javascript though.

Comment: also appears that the markup is not valid (according to validator.w3.org)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("formControl")
```

And two things:

1. Make sure that the form isn't inside of a frame on the page.  If it is, you will have to switch to the frame (it is functionally a different webpage displayed in a box.)
2. Make sure that you've got the right browser window selected, if you're manipulating multiple windows, you're going to have to switch to the one you want to search through.

Comment: "Make sure that you've got the right browser window selected, if you're manipulating multiple windows, you're going to have to switch to the one you want to search through." Thank you so much! That was the problem :) In the step before this one, I had clicked on a link that opened a new window, and I had assumed that that window would automatically be the active one. Thanks!!